# How to create non-transactional JUnit integration tests in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

An integration test class is annotated with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = IntegrationTestConfig.class)
```

It's not supposed to run in a transaction so **isn't** marked as `@Transactional` but I'm getting errors when trying to perform persist, merge etc. operations on the `EntityManager`, which is injected using `@PersistenceContext`:

> No transactional EntityManager available

How can this be resolved?

**EDIT:**
As requested in the comments, the Spring version is 4.1.0.RELEASE and `IntegrationTestConfig` is below:

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class IntegrationTestConfig {
    /**
     * Override the existing JPA data source bean with a test data source.
     * @return test data source
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        final SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(org.h2.Driver.class);
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS mydb");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems some config issue. Can you provide IntegrationTestConfig details. and Spring version ?

Comment: @vels4j Thanks for the reply, have added these to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure that you are never going to call `entityManager.flush()`, obtain the `PersistenceContext` as follows:

```
@PersistenceContext(type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

---

Why is this needed? Spring Data JPA hands out what is called a shared `EntityManager` when the [`@PersistenceContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html) annotation is used (without any attributes).  Full details for this are available in the [JavaDocs for `org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/SharedEntityManagerCreator.html).  This class maintains a lookup table where the `EntityManager` methods `flush`, `merge`, `persist`, `refresh` and `remove` are required to be run inside a transaction.  So, any time it encounters a method call that is not inside a transaction, it bails out.

The annotation `@PersistenceContext` has a `type` attribute that can be set to one of `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` or `PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION`, with the later being the default.  Therefore, the default `@PersistenceContext` causes `SharedEntityManagerCreator` to look for a transaction and bail out if none is found.

Using `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED` bypasses the need to check for a transaction when obtaining the `EntityManager` and therefore the code should work.

---

`flush` still cannot be called without a transaction because the JPA providers require it to be called only within a transactional context.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks. In that case I think I'm going to use transactions but more sparingly, i.e. one transaction to populate the test data, various @Transactional annotations that are already spread amongst the services and one at the end to clean up.